# Typescript date subtraction results in 0 instead of actual difference in time.

Tags: javascript, typescript, date

I have two date objects Date in the form of

```
let t1 = 2015-03-26T09:43:39.504
let t2 = 2015-03-26T10:43:39.504
```

(These two times are retrieved by calling an API REST call).

How would I get the difference in time between the two (in the form of seconds)?

I've tried doing t1-t2 but the result is always 0.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [getTime](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime) which returns the number of milliseconds since 1 January 1970 00:00:00.

```
let t1 = new Date('2015-03-26T09:43:39.504')
let t2 = new Date('2015-03-26T10:43:39.504')
const diff = (t2.getTime() - t1.getTime()) / 1000
```